# The minimal polynomial $\sigma(\alpha)$ on $K$ is also $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, minimal-polynomials

> Let $K $ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha$ a complexe number which
>   is algebraic on $K$ and $f(x) \in K[x]$ the minimal polynomial of
>   $\alpha$ on $K$. Show that if $\sigma: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a ring homomorphism such that $\sigma|_K=id|_K$, then the minimal polynomial $\sigma(\alpha)$ on $K$ is also $f(x)$.

I'm blocked on this problem for a while. Is anyone could give me a good hint to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $\sigma(a)=a$ for all $a\in K$. Using this, you can show that 
$$0=\sigma(0)=\sigma(f(\alpha))=f(\sigma(\alpha))$$
(why?).

This shows that the minimal polynomial for $\sigma(\alpha)$ over $K$ divides $f$. But, since $f$ is irreducible, . . .

Answer (score 1):

Hint : if a monic polynomial $g \in K[x]$ is irreducible and has $\sigma(\alpha)$ as root, then $g$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sigma(\alpha)$ over $K$. Then you just have to show that $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root of $g := f$.